# Is RequestMapping removed from Spring 3.2.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is RequestMapping removed from Spring 3.2.1.

I am working on a new project and trying to use Spring 3.2.1...  But my IDEA and Maven cant find RequestMapping in Spring.. below is my controller:

```
package org.sample.jquery.controller;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import static org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/request")
public class RequestController {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(RequestController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayRequestPage() {

        return new ModelAndView("input");

    }

}
```

and here is my pom.xml.... It looks like RequestMapping was removed from Spring 3.2.1

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jQueryExamples</groupId>
    <artifactId>jQueryExamples</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jQueryExamples Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            ...
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <springframework-version>3.2.1.RELEASE</springframework-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--  the following is for spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--  This is for logging with log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- this is for junit testing -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>jQueryExamples</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by an issue in 3.2.1 that has been fixed for 3.2.2:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10218

That said, since you're using @RequestMapping, your pom should include a dependency on spring-web rather than relying on the transitive dependency from spring-webmvc to spring-web. So I recommend adding that dependency in any case.

Answer (score 3):

It should be in

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

There was a bug in 3.2.1, [fixed in 3.2.2](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10218), where the `spring-webmvc` dependency didn't bring in `spring-web` and `spring-context`, so you had to manually declare the dependency.

It's `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;`

Comment: Np, considering checking the answer if it helped you, once you can.

Comment: One thing to note is that spring-webmvc's pom.xml normally brings spring-web in transitively. However, due to a bug spring-web is not brought in transitively in 3.2.1. The issue will be fixed in the 3.2.2 release. For more info see the JIRA https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10218

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the RequestMapping annotation is part of Spring 3.2.1, according to the JavaDoc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/

Maybe you need to add the Spring MVC libraries to your project ?